# WNS PushNotificationChannelManager not using system proxy

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, push-notification

G'day all,

We're creating a Windows 8 Metro application for use behind a corporate firewall, but are having problems with the proxy configuration when it comes to supporting push notifications via WNS.

The system proxy is configured fine for the desktop, and is also configured correctly when viewed via

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

I have a very simple application to reproduce the issues.  When making a normal webrequest via the following code:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("https://sincd.wns.windows.com");
var response = await req.GetResponseAsync();
TxtMessage.Text = "Content-Length: " + response.ContentLength;
```

I get data back correctly, and a wireshark trace shows the packets connecting to the internal proxy as expected.

Unfortunately, attempting to create the push channel via

```
var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

fails to return (resulting in a timeout).  The wireshark track shows three attempts to connect directly to the upstream server (ie NOT the proxy) as shown below:

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  4 0.404841    10.65.94.80           sincd.wns.windows.com TCP      66     netadmin > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
  5 3.406263    10.65.94.80           sincd.wns.windows.com TCP      66     netadmin > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
  6 9.406293    10.65.94.80           sincd.wns.windows.com TCP      62     netadmin > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
```

The ProxyConfiguration information returned from a call to NetworkInformation.GetProxyConfigurationAsync() also shows the proxy entry configured correctly.

Is there any way to manually configure the proxy information for the PushNotificationChannelManager?

Cheers,

Comment: Although I dont know the details, communicating with MPNS requires some very specific proxy configuration. Have heard of this problem elsewhere. Solution? sorry I have no idea.

Comment: Are you behind an authenticated proxy?

Comment: We are behind an authenticating proxy.  *.windows.com has been opened for unauthenticated access.  Our original thought was that the proxy change had been made incorrectly, however the fact the packets don't target the proxy, and the failure to receive a 407 back over the wire lead me to conclude there's an issue locally.  Once I see it hit the proxy and _still_ not work I'll be harassing the ops guys.